# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when running SP

Tags: oracle

I'm troubled with this error when running SP, I don't know why. pls help me

error in line AND thlt.CODE  =  ' || p_CODE|| ' when CODE is varchar2

A_ID NUMBER, P_A_Ids VARCHAR2, v_expression VARCHAR2, p_CODE VARCHAR2

```
...
OPEN v_cursor FOR
             ' SELECT thltCt.A_ID A_ID,
                        Sum( ' ||  v_expression || ' ) "VALUE"     
                FROM tableA thlt join tableB thltCt on thlt.ID = thltCt.THLT_ID  
                WHERE thlt.LS IS NOT NULL  
                      AND thlt.CODE  =  ' || p_CODE|| '   
                      AND thltCt.A_ID IN (' || P_A_Ids || ' )  
                GROUP BY (thltCt.A_ID)';
```

Comment: you need double ' if p_CODE is a string  = AND thlt.CODE  =  '' ' || p_CODE|| ' ''

Comment: its impossible to undestand if you dont share full code table definitions and inputs

Comment: yes, CODE is varchar2

Comment: can you share v_expressin and P_A_Ids types too ?

Comment: and that line is the cause of this error. If I remove that line SQL run normally

Comment: can you try my string i shared at answers ?

Comment: 01ZZ is the code ? what is the input for p_CODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments i think it will work like this :

```
' SELECT thltCt.A_ID A_ID,
                        Sum( ' ||  v_expression || ' ) "VALUE"     
                FROM tableA thlt join tableB thltCt on thlt.ID = thltCt.THLT_ID  
                WHERE thlt.LS IS NOT NULL  
                      AND thlt.CODE  =  '' ' || p_CODE|| ' ''  
                      AND thltCt.A_ID IN ( ' || P_A_Ids || ' )  
                GROUP BY (thltCt.A_ID)';
```

Comment: no problem it was common thing we face at work